# Como organizar o desenvolvimento de um projeto

Tags: php, jquery, html, uml

Pergunto de maneira bem abrangente aplicado tanto a Desktop quanto Web, se for muito diferente os métodos, peço que me orientem.

Possuo alguns clientes, e com o passar de alguns meses, vejo que ao crescer dos projetos (Tanto web quanto desktop) fica difícil de outros trabalharem no mesmo projeto, e difícil até para mim me encontrar e me organizar no próprio projeto.

No caso do WEB: Como dividir o arquivos [php](/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) e [html](/questions/tagged/html) nas pastas e subpastas? E como documentar algo do tipo? Existe documentação?

No caso do Desktop: Como dividir o banco de dados, das validações e da programação daquele determinado formulário?

Pois bem, gostaria que me dissessem quais são os passos para uma perfeita organização e desenvolvimento de um projeto. Seria o UML? Apenas isso bastaria?

Comment: UML é uma linguagem visual para modelar diversos conceitos ou processos de uma aplicação. Não é necessário para a organização de um projeto, é apenas uma forma de duas ou mais pessoas conseguirem botar seus pensamentos de nível mais baixo sobre desenvolvimento no papel.

Comment: Não estou pedindo opinião. Estou querendo saber que meios, que programas, que padrões podem ser utilizados para ter um projeto organizado onde qualquer programador novo que entre na empresa consiga entender e tocar o projeto adiante, ou até, eu mesmo consiga facilmente fazer manutenção sem ficar extenso e complicado. O único meio que já ouvi falar foi UML e aparentemente não é essa a proposta dele, pelo que li no comentário acima.

Comment: Se o software a ser desenvolvido cresceu então é conveniente você estudar o SWEBOK (Guide to the Software Engineering Body of Knowledge) http://www.computer.org/portal/web/swebok. Se você tem uma equipe então tem um projeto e precisa das técnicas de gerenciamento de projetos como o conjunto de práticas descritas no PMBOK (Project Management Body of Knowledge) da PMI (Project Management Institute).

Answer (score 3):

### [MVC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC)

Uma prática amplamente adotada no mercado atual é a utilização do modelo MVC (Model-view-controller).
Basicamente você separa seus arquivos em pastas diferentes, separando a camada de visualização/apresentação (html, js, css), da camada de negócios (banco de dados, lógica de negócios), da camada de controle, que faz a ponte entre a camada de negócios e apresentação.

### [Frameworks](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework)

A utilização de frameworks full-stack tabém facilita e muito na organização dos projetos, já que os mesmo já vem modelados utilizando todos esses conceitos.

Tente usar um framework e observe sua estrutura.

Em [php](/questions/tagged/php), aconselho o [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) ou [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

[Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) tem ditado muitas tendências em relação a organização dos frameworks, além de ter uma comunidade muito ativa, que está sempre tentando resolver esses tipos de problemas, convido você a conhecer também.

Como você citou problemas com validações, segue o link de como o Rails encara as [validações](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) de formulários.

Comment: Queria adicionar o Framework Cakephp, aconselho bastante.

Comment: +1 para o Laravel, se não for possível usar o Rails.